# How to run python scripts (in different virtualenvs) with supervisord?

Tags: supervisord, pipenv

I'd like to run my scripts with supervisord (version: 4.0.0.dev0),
each script has it's own virtualenv.
I couldn't figure out how to activate through supervisord the corresponding  virtualenv and then run those python scripts (pipenv version 2018.10.13).
I need both operations:

1. `pipenv shell` in the directory.
2. `pipenv run python demo1.py`

Each python script runs on a different virtualenv, my conf for each script looks similar to this:

```
[program:my_script1]
command=pipenv run python demo1.py
directory=/path/to/my_directory
```

a bash wrapper script hasn't resolved the issue,
so how do i activate my virtualenv and afterwards run my script with supervisord?

any suggestion/assistance will be helpful,

Thank you all!